# Place to study Zohar

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, adult-learning, yeshiva-school, zohar

What is a good place for an American to learn Zohar in person (anywhere internationally)? (This question is for a friend who is much more learned than I am).

Comment: Hebrew University?

Comment: The Kabbalah Center?  **Just kidding!!**

Comment: @Daniel hah! no

Answer (score 2):

There are several good and renowned Kabbalistic Yeshivot in Jerusalem.  Many of those offer shiurim in Zohar(as well as other subjects) provided one is qualified for them.
Nahar Shalom offers two one hour shiurim each day, one under the Rosh Yeshiva Rav Benayahu Shmueli and one under Rav David HaKohen.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm going to leave this question opened for a bit to grab more answers, but this is helpful.

Comment: This Michael Tzadok is a RASHA , SINNER AND MAKES OTHER SIN, HE'S NOT JEWISH, HE'S A MISSIONARY, WATCH A MENUVAL UGH!!!  WATCH THIS VIDEO FROM RABBI TUVIA SINGER - https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=8g71VZrjCpg

Comment: Please be aware that the author of this answer, "Michael Tzadok," has recently been [outed as a Christian missionary](https://www.northjersey.com/story/news/new-jersey/2021/05/03/orthodox-rabbi-nj-accused-double-life-missionary-israel/4868837001/). His real name is Michael Elk. Please also see [here](https://youtu.be/8N6sPqFBt3A) and [here](https://youtu.be/8g71VZrjCpg).